# How do I check if a h264 video contains b-frames?

Tags: video, h.264, ffprobe

I'm using [ffprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) right now but I don't if it supports showing whether the video contains [b-frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) and what could be the syntax. Can I do this with ffprobe and so, how, or is there any other free alternative that could do this?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. I'm not asking for a shopping recommendation, but for a way to check if an h264 video contains b-frames.

Comment: software recommendation is the same thing as a shopping recommendation.  Take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) for more info.

Comment: According to that meta post, this question is exactly how you should ask for something that may require a software recommendation.

Comment: I've edited your question to be more about the technology, than a software rec.  Feel free to rollback if you disagree, however IMO your original edit was more about asking for a "tool" to do the work, instead of asking how to do something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a way. With ffprobe:

```
ffprobe -show_frames videofilename.mp4 > outputfile.txt
```

Then you just look for the pict_type entries, which will be either I, P, or B. B denotes a b-frame.

Comment: `ffprobe -show_frames input.mp4 | grep "pict_type"`

Comment: verified also works for containers other than mp4, and even h264 nalu streams without a container(aka h264 AnnexB stream, which simply use defined sperator to concat all NAL units).